# Read image png format as bitmap and save it as png with same hash

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to import png file as Bitmap and save it as same type(png) but the hash is not the same.

Is it possible to save the bitmap with the same file to get the same hash as before?

What i tried is:

```
private static void VaryQualityLevel(string filename)
{
    // Get a bitmap.
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(filename);
    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);

    // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID 
    // for the Quality parameter category.
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter 
    // objects. In this case, there is only one 
    // EncoderParameter object in the array.
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.png", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

    myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityHundred.png", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

    // Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.
    myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    bmp1.Save(@"test5.png", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{

    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are re-saving it with different settings so it would not be the same. If you want it to be the same why not just copy the original instead?

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to avoid misleading code like this: `ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);` (And why are you saving PNG images as file with a .jpg extension?)

Comment: And `// Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.` when you are saving as png.

Comment: my mistake its need to be png i will change my question

Comment: Of course the hash is not the same. The .Net framework doesn't have particularly good png compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, I wouldn't expect loading an image and then encoding it again to result in the exact same bytes, which is what your hash would depend on. Different encoders will have different implementations - I could imagine situations where even encoders which encoded semantically equivalent information could do so using a different byte output. (In some cases, even the *same* encoder could do that, if it included a timestamp or a GUID or something similar.)

If you require the exact same bytes as the original file, I'd just copy the file instead.

Comment: Excellent points. I once had to compare generated PDFs and ended up programming a `FileStream` subclass that blanked out GUIDs and time stamps as I hashed the file. For comparing images, though, the only really reliable way would be to just compare the pixel data.